# Unable to mute audio output on Twilio Softphone

Tags: twilio, webrtc, html5-audio

I am attempting to temporarily mute the output stream from the Twilio Softphone. Note that this is different than muting the microphone. I want to mute the speakers.

The first thing I noticed was that the function for getRemoteStream() is undefined on Connection even though it's documented here.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#getRemoteStream

So I attempted to find a way around this by getting the stream from here.

```
Twilio.Device.activeConnection().mediaStream.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]
```

I should be able to call the following to mute the output stream but it isn't working.

```
Twilio.Device.activeConnection().mediaStream.stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
```

Is there a better way to do this with the Twilio Softphone?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this was just a problem with an older version of the Twilio Softphone (1.3). After upgrading to the latest (1.5) the following worked.

```
Twilio.Device.activeConnection().getRemoteStream().getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false
```

Comment: Thanks! You save my day!